# Read Room database entity from a service android

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I'm trying to read a value from room database of android in a ListenerService class.

```
repository.responseCode("status");
        repository.responseCode("status").observe(
                MainActivity.class,flagValue -> {
                    if(flagValue!=null){

                    }
                }
        );
```

But it says wrong first type argument at "MainActivity.class" at above code.
Can I read any room db value from a service?

Comment: In which class are you calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass **LifecycleOwner** and **Observer** implementation to observe method.
You can pass your activity's instance directly as first parameter.
You are passing MainActivity **Class**'s instance.

if you are writing in Activity you can repace with this.

```
repository.responseCode("status").observe(
                this,flagValue -> {
                    if(flagValue!=null){

                    }
                }
        );
```